# Component isn't saving its value in the database

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte

I'm having an issue saving an option in the data base.

For this problem I had to create a componente in Svelte and it basically just saves the States of the US, but when I'm trying to save it in the data base (using a typescript file where I'm using Superforms for sveltekit) it doesn't save it! But the rest of the data is saved.

StatePicker.svelte

```
<script lang="ts">
    import MaterialSelect from './MaterialSelect.svelte';

    export let invalid = '';
    export let value: string = '';
    export let label = 'State';
    export let name = 'state';
    export let id = 'state';
    export let placeholder = ' ';
    export let disabled = false;
    export let readonly = false;
    export let required = false;

    const STATES = [
        { state: 'Alabama', abbreviation: 'AL' },
        { state: 'Alaska', abbreviation: 'AK' },
        { state: 'Arizona', abbreviation: 'AZ' },
        { state: 'Arkansas', abbreviation: 'AR' },
        { state: 'California', abbreviation: 'CA' },
        { state: 'Colorado', abbreviation: 'CO' },
        { state: 'Connecticut', abbreviation: 'CT' },
        { state: 'Delaware', abbreviation: 'DE' },
        { state: 'Florida', abbreviation: 'FL' },
        { state: 'Georgia', abbreviation: 'GA' },
        { state: 'Hawaii', abbreviation: 'HI' },
        { state: 'Idaho', abbreviation: 'ID' },
        { state: 'Illinois', abbreviation: 'IL' },
        { state: 'Indiana', abbreviation: 'IN' },
        { state: 'Iowa', abbreviation: 'IA' },
        { state: 'Kansas', abbreviation: 'KS' },
        { state: 'Kentucky', abbreviation: 'KY' },
        { state: 'Louisiana', abbreviation: 'LA' },
        { state: 'Maine', abbreviation: 'ME' },
        { state: 'Maryland', abbreviation: 'MD' },
        { state: 'Massachusetts', abbreviation: 'MA' },
        { state: 'Michigan', abbreviation: 'MI' },
        { state: 'Minnesota', abbreviation: 'MN' },
        { state: 'Mississippi', abbreviation: 'MS' },
        { state: 'Missouri', abbreviation: 'MO' },
        { state: 'Montana', abbreviation: 'MT' },
        { state: 'Nebraska', abbreviation: 'NE' },
        { state: 'Nevada', abbreviation: 'NV' },
        { state: 'New Hampshire', abbreviation: 'NH' },
        { state: 'New Jersey', abbreviation: 'NJ' },
        { state: 'New Mexico', abbreviation: 'NM' },
        { state: 'New York', abbreviation: 'NY' },
        { state: 'North Carolina', abbreviation: 'NC' },
        { state: 'North Dakota', abbreviation: 'ND' },
        { state: 'Ohio', abbreviation: 'OH' },
        { state: 'Oklahoma', abbreviation: 'OK' },
        { state: 'Oregon', abbreviation: 'OR' },
        { state: 'Pennsylvania', abbreviation: 'PA' },
        { state: 'Rhode Island', abbreviation: 'RI' },
        { state: 'South Carolina', abbreviation: 'SC' },
        { state: 'South Dakota', abbreviation: 'SD' },
        { state: 'Tennessee', abbreviation: 'TN' },
        { state: 'Texas', abbreviation: 'TX' },
        { state: 'Utah', abbreviation: 'UT' },
        { state: 'Vermont', abbreviation: 'VT' },
        { state: 'Virginia', abbreviation: 'VA' },
        { state: 'Washington', abbreviation: 'WA' },
        { state: 'West Virginia', abbreviation: 'WV' },
        { state: 'Wisconsin', abbreviation: 'WI' },
        { state: 'Wyoming', abbreviation: 'WY' }
    ];
</script>

<MaterialSelect {label} value={value} {id} {disabled}>
    {#each STATES as { state, abbreviation }}
        <option value={state}>{abbreviation}</option>
    {/each}
</MaterialSelect>
```

This is the typescript code i'm using to store it in the db and it works with the everything except StatePicker

```
import type { Actions, PageServerLoad } from './$types';
import { Schema, z } from 'zod';
import { message, superValidate } from 'sveltekit-superforms/server';

const insuranceCompanySchema = z.object({
    name: z.string().nonempty(),
    street: z.string(),
    city: z.string(),
    state: z.string(),
    zip: z.string().regex(/^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$/),
    phone: z.string().regex(/^\d{10}$/),
    website: z.string().url()
});

export const load = (async ({ locals, params }) => {
    const form = await superValidate(insuranceCompanySchema);
    console.log('bop');
    return {
        form
    };
}) satisfies PageServerLoad;

export const actions = {
    default: async ({ request, locals, params }) => {
        const form = await superValidate(request, insuranceCompanySchema);
        console.log(form.errors);
        if (!form.valid) {
            console.log('errors0', form.errors);
            return message(form, {
                type: 'error',
                msg: 'Invalid Form',
                title: 'Error'
            });
        }

        const { data: insertCompanyData, error } = await locals.supabase
            .from('insurance_companies')
            .insert({
                name: form.data.name,
                street: form.data.street,
                city: form.data.city,
                state: form.data.state,
                zip_code: form.data.zip,
                phone: form.data.phone,
                website: form.data.website
            });

            console.log(form.errors)

            console.log(form.errors)

        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return {
                error: error,
                form
            };
        }

        return message(form, {
            type: 'success',
            title: 'Inserted',
            msg: 'A company has been inserted'
        });
    }
} satisfies Actions;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have already fixed it! I hope that this helps someone if it's needed

In this part I had no a {name} value

```
<MaterialSelect {label} {value} {id} {disabled} {name}>
    {#each STATES as { state, abbreviation }}
        <option value={abbreviation}>{abbreviation}</option>
    {/each}
</MaterialSelect>
```

So I had to check the component MaterialSelect and add a variable called "name" and add it into the placeholder:

MaterialSelect.svelte

```
<script lang="ts">
    import Icon from '@iconify/svelte';
    export let id = 'id';
    export let disabled = false;
    export let label = 'Select an option';
    export let value: any = undefined;
    export let name = 'name';

    $: {
        console.log('value is: ', value);
    }
</script>

<div class="relative">
    <span class="ml-2 text-[10px] text-gray-500 {disabled && 'text-gray-300'} absolute -top-2"
        >{label}</span
    >
    <Icon
        icon="bx:chevron-down"
        class="text-xl text-gray-500 {disabled && 'text-gray-300'} absolute right-0 top-1/3"
    />
    <select
        placeholder="Select an option"
        {disabled}
        bind:value
        {id}
        {name}
        class="block w-full border-0 border-b-2 bg-transparent px-0 py-2.5 text-sm {disabled
            ? 'border-gray-200'
            : 'border-gray-300'} peer appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:ring-0"
    >
        <option hidden selected={value === undefined || value === null}>-</option>
        <slot />
    </select>
</div>
```

*emphasized text*